# Mercurial and Hudson on web hosting. Can I install Mercurial

Tags: linux, mercurial, hudson, hudson-plugins

I have a hosting package where I have a private Tomcat and I run Hudson. I wanted to start using Mercurial and BitBucket (which is fantastic btw), my problem is that Hudson or the Mercurial plugin doesn't bundle Mercurial in the same way it does Subversion and you have to point your plugin to your Mercurial install. 
My hosting doesn't have Mercurial installed so I tried  (with limited linux skills) to install it myself.

I soon found out that I need run the install as root which I obviously don't have. Even if I run it without root it still tries to write to directories which have only root access.

Am I being missing something or does it sound like I won't be able to install it without root permissions?

Thanks,
Shawn

Comment: This might be a difficult problem to crack via Stack Overflow (hopefully it isn't). Have you considered asking your hosting service to install Mercurial for you?

Comment: I actually tried this and reverted to subversion (not that I am saying you should) but the reason I mentioned is that my hosting company shut down my site as they said that Hudson was considered malicious software as it has a listening tcp port. I also had a private Tomcat install

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this [guide to installing mercurial on a web host](http://blog.tlensing.org/2010/04/12/installing-mercurial-on-a-shared-web-server-without-root-access-hosteurope/) will help.